# Trocar ponto por virgula em preço

Tags: javascript

Bom dia, tenho esse codigo para atualizar o total.

Preciso trocar o .(ponto) por ,(virgula). Como faço?

**Código :**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

 $("#evento_quantidade").change(function() {
 var qtd = $(this).val();
 var valor = $("#precoSoma").val();
 var calculo = qtd * valor;
 var n = calculo.toFixed(2);     
 $("#total_compra").val(n);

 });


 });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É so colocar a função `replace` para trocar o ponto pela virgula.

Teste trocar o código abaixo e me fale depois se funcionou

**Como está :**

```
$("#total_compra").val(n);
```

**Como deve ficar :**

```
$("#total_compra").val(n.replace(".", ","));
```

Comment: Perfeito :D abç lek